# Java: Android class and api package hierarchy inheritance

Tags: java, class, inheritance, package, hierarchy

I’m not sure if I’ve grasped some basic java on class & package hierarchy, please confirm or correct the following:

```
  java.lang.Object  

         android.view.View 

                android.view.ViewGroup 

                         android.widget.RelativeLayout
```

**java.lang.Object**

//1) Object is a super class?

**android.view.View**

//2) View class extends Object class and View is in view package?

**android.view.ViewGroup**

//3) ViewGroup class extends View class, both classes are in view package?

**android.widget.RelativeLayout**

//4)There is package calle widget that contains a RelativeLayout class that extends ViewGroup?

android reference:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html

Thanks Luther

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of that is correct. Need I say more?

Comment: Thanks, just was double checking

Comment: there you go, I had to wait 5 min